# C# WebBrowser Body is null, GetElementById returns null

Tags: c#, winforms, dom, browser, web

I am loading a local HTML page using the WebBrowser control.

```
namespace ConfigEditorWinForms
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public partial class ConfigEditorForm : Form
    {
        String _currentConfigFilePath = null;


        public ConfigEditorForm()
        {
            Load += new EventHandler(ConfigEditorForm_Load);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConfigEditorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;
            webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
          //webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(OnDocumentCompleted);

            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/ConfigEditor/ConfigEditor.html", curDir));
        }

        private void OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Document completed");
        }

        public string GetFileContents(String path)
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        }

        public void SaveFileContents(String path, String contents)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"XXX";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
                HtmlElement fileToOpenInput = doc.GetElementById("fileToOpenInput");
                fileToOpenInput.InvokeMember("onchange", new object[1] { openFileDialog.FileName });
                _currentConfigFilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my computer :

- The document completed event is fired twice
- Opening a file from the menu works fine too

On another computer :

- The document completed event is only fired (ONCE) when the executable is run as administrator
- Document.Body is null and Document.GetElementById returns null too, despite the document completed event being fired several seconds before.

What's going on please ?

Thank you. :)

Comment: have you stepped through the code..? what is the value when it works on your machine for this line `HtmlElement fileToOpenInput = doc.GetElementById("fileToOpenInput");` perhaps the file is not found on their machine and or the path(s) that you have on your machine are not the same on others and or remote machines.. use the debugger and provide us with more information in regards to filename / filepaths

Comment: On my machine `fileToOpenInput` contains a valid HtmlElement (actually it's an input). I am able to see attributes i defined in the HTML using the debugger. It seems fine.
The path is always relative, it searches for `./ConfigEditor/ConfigEditor.html`. I thought that, running it in debug mode (on my machine where it works) might have set a different working directory, but running it without debugging, by simply click the .exe works fine too.

Comment: I got some more info though. On the machine where it doesn't work, the document completed event is only fired once, when it's fired twice on my machine where it works. I guess it's simply unable to load the document. Could it be user right-related ? Than you.